Problem with Jest on NodeJs (Typescript): SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
I need some help with testing library Jest (on NodeJS + TS). Here is my error message:
Details:
/node_modules/nanoid/index.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import { webcrypto as crypto } from 'node:crypto'
                                                                                      ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

  1 | import {TRPCError} from '@trpc/server';
> 2 | import {customAlphabet} from 'nanoid';
    | ^
  3 | import {Logger} from 'pino';
  4 |
  5 | import {

I have configured my jest.config.cjs file as required:
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.[jt]sx?$': 'ts-jest': 'ts-jest'
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '/node_modules/(?!nanoid)'
  ]
};

ts.config.json is configured properly as well:
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "ESNext",
      "module": "ESNext",
      "strict": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
      "moduleResolution": "node"
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*", "jest.config.cjs"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"]
  }

However, the issue with ECMAscript modules for Jest still persists. Maybe someone also had such a problem and can help with this?
Thanks in advance!

Edited jest.config.cjs file:
changed
transform: {
'^.+\.[jt]sx?$': 'ts-jest'
},
added this file to tsconfig; however, didn't help with the issue

Just to understanding more, are you using babel config in your project?

Somehow it started working! I didn't do anything special - just tried to remove node modules and installed them again and it worked. Probably was an glitch or something
*PS. and no, no babel was used in the project
